# Neo4j 3.2.3: dump command does not find database

Tags: database, neo4j

I am newbie on the field of graph databases and now I am trying to export my Neo4j 3.2.3 graph database by dump command from neo4j-admin tool on Windows 10, but command everytime failed because is not able to find my graph database. I do not know how to list names of databases running on my PC and check the name of my database. I expected that the name of database corresponds with the name of folder location of my database but it does not work. Could somebody help me?

[Neo4j GUI client with the destination of my database folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hru53.png)
[Failing command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZYT1.png)

Comment: The exe version has a few quirks in its interaction with the command line tools, as I think the directory structure is different than what the command line tools expect. If you can, try out the zipped version of Neo4j instead.

Comment: You were right @InverseFalcon . I downloaded zipped version Neo4j 3.3.0, set path to my old database folder in file _%Neo4j HOME%/conf/neo4j.conf_  value _dbms.directories.data_. After that I uninstall my old Neo4j and run dump command without problems. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great! I'll change that to an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exe version has a few quirks in its interaction with the command line tools, as I think the directory structure is different than what the command line tools expect.

If you can, try out the zipped version of Neo4j instead.