# How to dumping database created in Mac OS X with neo4j Desktop?

Tags: macos, neo4j

I have been trying to dump a database I have created using neo4j Desktop app version 3.3.0 on Mac OS X.  The documentation said that I need to use neo4j-admin on command line.  This was not installed as part of the Desktop version, so I installed neo4j v3.3.0 with homebrew, and got neo4j-admin.

But while running command:

```
neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=~/mydatabase.db
```

I always get the error:

```
command failed: database does not exist: graph.db
```

I have searched here and on google, and the only thing I found has been

[Neo4j 3.2.3: dump command does not find database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132234/neo4j-3-2-3-dump-command-does-not-find-database)

But the answer there is quite vague and I am not too sure what it means, as I am new to neo4j.  I gathered that the desktop version is not compatible with the command-line, and that one needs to stick purely with the command-line version, am I understanding this wrong?

I can find graph.db in:

```
$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases
```

But neo4j-admin seems to just refuse to find it, and setting the environment variables did not solve the problem.  And I cannot supply a path to the database as neo4j-admin doesn't take paths.

If I know where neo4j-admin is trying to look for the database, then I can hopefully solve the problem by provide a symbolic link to it, but at the moment I have no idea where it is looking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neo4j-admin` is probably looking for `graph.db` in the same directory that your Homebrew Neo4j is installed. You can find out where that is by doing `which neo4j-admin`, then checking that directory with `ls -al` to see where Homebrew's actually storing the files.

It'll be somewhere like `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/<version number>/bin`, and by default (at least with Neo4j 3.1.1) it'll expect the database to be in `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/<version number>/libexec/data/databases/`.

Comment: Also, furthermore, I have found the executables from the desktop version in the bin directory of the desktop version's installation directories, and this version worked directly with the database I have created.